# assign value from char* to struct in6_addr

Tags: c, struct, ipv6

I want the the user to enter an Ipv6 address and I should be able to assign it to an ipv6 address variable of the type : struct in6_addr

Since the arguments input from console ie argv is of char* type

while I try to assign the value from char* to struct in6addr variable it display incompatibility error

I dont seem to find any conversion function from char* to  struct in6_addr ipv6 format . none of teh fucntions inet_ntop or inet_pton have return type of struct in6_addr  .

Please help

Comment: `inet_pton()` will do the job. There is an example on how to use it on the bottom of the man-page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html

Comment: hello thanks for helping , but as i have put i don't want it to be in binary form . Instead it should be in struct in6_addr format so that my variable for ipv6 can take this value as assignment .

Comment: `struct in6_addr` is a binary representation of an IPv6 address and `inet_pton()` does exactly fill a `struct in6_addr` if told to do so by getting passed `AF_INET6` as 1st argument.